# Error using a django template

Tags: python, django, import, module, pip

I'm trying to use a Django template, but even thought I've used pip install, when I write down this:

```
from django.templated_email import send_templated_mail
```

I get this error (I want to use this template: https://github.com/bradwhittington/django-templated-email) :

```
ImportError at /
No module named templated_email
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.4
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    No module named templated_email
Exception Location: /Users/user/folder/MyProyect/proyect/templated_email/send_email.py in <module>, line 26
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.1
Python Path:    ['/Users/user/folder/MyProyect/proyect',
   '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.0-py2.7.egg',
   '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
   '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
   '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
   '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
   '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
   '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python',
   '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
   '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
   '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
   '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC',
   '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages',
   '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info']
Server time:    mar, 15 Ene 2013 12:04:27 +0100
```

If anyone know how to solve this problem, please, tell me how (If there's an example that'll be great)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, in the instructions it doesn't say that you need to add in settings.py, in INSTALLED_APPS 'templated_email'

Answer (score 1):

Remove `django.` from this line:

```
from django.templated_email import send_templated_mail
```

Comment: When i do it I get 
ImportError at /
cannot import name send_templated_mail, I get cannot import name, while having it I get cannot import module

Comment: Make sure you installed it in the correct environment that you are using (if you are using virtualenv). Otherwise, stop and restart your server.

Answer (score 0):

You should import  like this `from templated_email import send_templated_mail` instead of `from django.templated_email import send_templated_mail`